# How to add objects in a 360 generated image

Tags: 3d, aframe, 8thwall-xr

I am generating 360 images using BlockadeLabs and I am creating a portal out of them. I am trying to add 3D objects inside his portal but they look like "floating" in the air. Is there a way to make them feel "grounded"?

Also glowing :)

Cheers,
Teddy